# Android SDK: cannot add widgets to main.xml through drag and drop

Tags: android, eclipse, drag-and-drop, widget

As the titles state, I can't drag widgets onto the screen. Attempting to do so simply produces a dashed outline, but the widget isn't added. Different widgets cause differently-sized outlines to be created, so the application (Eclipse) is recognizing my input to some degree. No errors are produced either.

I've found no documentation on the drag-and-drop UI approach, probably because it's supposed to be self-explanatory (I had no problems doing the same thing on Qt, for example). Also note that I've gotten a basic "hello world" program working, both on an emulated device and on a smartphone.

I tried uploading a picture illustrating the problem but as I am a new user I don't have the permissions to do so.

EDIT: Well restarting Eclipse fixed the issue, though I still don't know what caused it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well restarting Eclipse fixed the issue, though I still don't know what caused it.